# What is the Google Play Plus One button URL for an app

Tags: android, google-play, google-plus

Hey this question is repeated from a year ago but no one yet answer it 
What is the correct url for the plus one button linking to the app store. The url im currently using is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=package.here
in the app it shows the number of plus ones in the play store when i press it it turned red and increase the number of +1 but when I go to play store nothing changed the same old number of +1 and the button is not clicked(red) still clickable 
am i using the correct url?